# Maven excludes the configuration processor package from the WAR

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, configuration

After upgrading spring-boot version from **2.1.8.RELEASE**  to **2.5.6**, the spring-boot-configuration-processor package was upgraded to.  When running the WAR we get the exception below that it cannot find the class and indeed the WAR does not contain the JAR (spring-boot-configuration-processor) for this package.

As workaround we have downgraded this package to 2.3.12.RELEASE which works on runtime. We have tried with versions 2.3.6 / 2.4.14 / 2.4.7 / 2.4.0 but the jar is not included in the WAR.

As I understood, the package is used by the IDE, so my question is: Why It is need in runtime?  Should it be included in my WAR? How does Maven decide to exclude a package from the WAR?

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name appointmentRepository defined in com.project.project.repositories.AppointmentRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot create inner bean (inner bean)#37291159 of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property entityManager; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name (inner bean)#37291159: Cannot resolve reference to bean entityManagerFactory while setting constructor argument; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name entityManagerFactory defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json.JSONException
```

application.properties:

```
com.project.file.maximumSize=5242880
com.project.file.contentTypes=application/pdf,image/png,image/jpeg
com.project.file.extensions=pdf,png,jpeg,jpg
com.project.file.maxFilesPerAttachmentType=5
```

additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json

```
{"properties": [
  {
    "name": "com.project.file.maximum-size",
    "type": "java.lang.Long",
    "description": "Sets the maximum valid size, in Bytes, for the uploaded attachments."
  },
  {
    "name": "com.project.file.content-types",
    "type": "java.util.List<java.lang.String>",
    "description": "A list of the authorized content types for the uploaded attachments."
  },
  {
    "name": "com.project.file.extensions",
    "type": "java.util.List<java.lang.String>",
    "description": "A list of the authorized extensions."
  }
]}
```

Comment: Can you post your pom file? That is the files used by Maven to configure the build (and the mistake might be found there)

Comment: I found the root cause , I was importing JSONObject and JSONException from  org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json  instead of org.json , that's why it wa called in the run time.  thanks @JensBaitinger

Answer (score 2):

The oldest version of springframework.boot.configurationprocessor  before x.x.x.RELEASE was on default scope compile that's why it was included in WEB-INF\lib, and did not cause classnotFoundException. I upgraded the version of the configurationprocessor package and changed my JSONObject and JSONException imports to json.org.